# Showing all posts that have the same 'tags' or 'categories' of the user

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am not sure if my method is the correct way of doing this in terms of my mysql schema because it is proving difficult as a user could have up to three tags and a post can also have up to three tags.

For example if a post has tags; Music, Technology. And a user has tags Music, Sports. The user would be able to see that post as the tag Music exists in both, the user profile and the post.

My tables are as follows:

**Profile** has columns:

```
Profile_id | tag1 | tag2 | tag3
```

**Post** has columns:

```
post_id | author | item | tag1 | tag2 | tag3.
```

Each tag in the table is related to a specific tag. E.g. `tag1`= Music, `tag2`= Sports etc.

A tag is inserted in the table dependant on whether the user ticks it when editing their profile or making a post, so tag could have a value `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

First up you need to fix your design. Create a Tags table and then a look-up table for each of Users and Posts which should make the solution much more apparent.

So your new structure will be:

**Profile:**

```
profile_id | Other_Profile_Info ...
```

**Post:**

```
post_id | author | item
```

**Tag:**

```
tag_id | tag
```

**Post_Tag:**

```
post_id | tag_id
```

**Profile_Tag:**

```
profile_id | tag_id
```

Then a query could look like:

```
SELECT p.* FROM Post AS p
   INNER JOIN Post_Tag AS PostTag ON p.post_id = PostTag.post_id
   INNER JOIN Profile_Tag AS ProfileTag ON PostTag.tag_id = ProfileTag.tag_id
   INNER JOIN Profile AS Profile ON Profile.profile_id = ProfileTag.profile_id
WHERE Profile.profile_id = 'MyID'
```

Or with Sub queries:

```
SELECT p.* FROM Post AS p 
WHERE p.post_id IN
   (SELECT post_id FROM Post_Tag WHERE tag_id IN
        (SELECT tag_id from Profile_Tag WHERE profile_id = 'MyID')
   )
```

Comment: I will try changing my structure now thanks. Would the post_id and tag_id of the Post_Tag table be foreign keys from the Post, and Tag tables?

Comment: @user1888378 Yes. The other thing you are doing here (beside properly normalizing your data) is removing you business logic from your table structure - so as the other answer points out, increasing or decreasing the tags per Profile / post does not impact your data structure.

Comment: Hi following this new schema is posing slightly difficult as when a user registers, I am now unsure in how to take the tags that they have entered? I.e. which table would I insert tags they have chosen

Comment: You should have 2 new tables: `Profile_Tag` and `Post_Tag`. I am assuming the new user selected tags would go into `Profile_Tag` with a foreign key in `Tag` and `Profile` to `tag_id` and profile_id in the same way you identified for `Post_Tag` above. You insert the user first then his tags once you have the `profile_id` (note I am assuming the `Profile` table is what holds your 'users'

Comment: Should I have manually pre-entered tags into the `Tag` table? I am struggling to understand how to get say a user's Music tag and enter it into their profile. Sorry I understand this new structure is more efficient however I have to now change over from my told schema to this new one!

Comment: @user1888378 Hesitating to say 'Manually' but your tags would need to either exist in the Tag table already or be created if a user added a new one. Assuming the Music tag: The music tag exists and has a Tag_id of 1. When a new user is created and selects (for this example just one tag) the Music tag, you are doing two inserts: 1. Insert the user into `Profile` and 2. Insert the `profile_id` and `tag_id` into the `Profile_Tag` table. To convert your current data you want to do something like INSERT INTO Tag (tagname) values (SELECT DISTINCT tag1 from Profile UNION SELECT DISTINCT tag2 ...)

Comment: After normalizing my database, the query you had provided in the answer works on the first post of a user, but then when posting again provides duplicates and I am unsure why and how it is duplicating data in some cases

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24526/discussion-between-matthew-and-user1888378)

Answer (score 2):

You ideally want to normalise your database more.  Creating a new table called `Tags` and having columns tag_id and tag_name will give you better flexibility than multiple columns.  For example what if you want a post to have 100 tags or more?

Creating a new table which governs the relationship between posts and tags (i.e. `post_tags`), and another for tags and users (`user_tags`) will let you do this much better.

For example you could then find all posts given a user's interests:

```
select p.*
from users u
join user_tags ut on u.user_id = ut.user_id
join post_tags pt on ut.tag_id = pt.tag_id
join posts p on p.id = pt.post_id
where u.user_name = 'theUser'
```

Remember you'll need your two many-to-many tables to have a compound key of both ids and check your query for possible duplicates etc.

Comment: I'd like to point out (because I can't do it on @matthew's answer, I don't think) that my script is likely to be better optimised at the database engine.  In general it's wise to avoid subqueries and `in` functions because you can't guarantee how many times the subquery will be resolved and `join`s are what databases are all about.

Comment: I included both in my answer, but you are correct in that I should switch the order and generally a join is better (and likely would be in this case). Also - have an upvote - will put you a step closer to being able to comment everywhere (50 rep required) :)

Comment: @Matthew, thanks :) When I commented you hadn't finished your answer I guess.

Comment: These popular tags are a race :) Sometimes I post iteratively (when I am feeling competitive).